# How to implement transient fault handling pattern with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I need to implement the following pattern:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx

I read on a book that following:

> If you are using Entity Framework 6 (EF 6), the retry logic for
>   transient faults is built in to the framework. When your EF 6 model is
>   in your project, you need to create a new class that derives from
>   DbConfiguration and customizes the execution strategy in the
>   constructor. EF 6 will look for classes that derive from
>   DbConfiguration in your project and use them to provide resiliency. To
>   set this, add a new Class file to your project and add using
>   statements for System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.

The code is as follows:

```
  public class EFConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public EFConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());
        }
    }
```

However I am not sure how to implement it on my code:

```
public class AppDataContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDataContext() : base("AppDataContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Module> Modulos { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Entidad> Entidades { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Propiedad> Propiedades { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

    }

 public class AppDataContextInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppDataContext context)
        {
            #region Seed Modules
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 1, ModuleName = "Contabilidad", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-ambulance" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 2, ModuleName = "Recursos Humanos", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-heartbeat" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Inventario", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-anchor" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Produccion", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-binoculars" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Ventas", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-coffee" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Compras", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-calendar-o" });
                context.Modulos.Add(new Module() { Id = 3, ModuleName = "Cotizaciones", FontAwesomeClass = "fa-building" });
            #endregion

            #region Seed Empresas
            context.Empresas.Add(new Empresa() { Id = 1,
                Nombre = "XYA",
                NIT = "900854343",
                NombreRepresentanteLegal = "Carla Peresz",
                TelefonoRepresentanteLegal = "123",
                NombreContacto = " Esteban Andres",
                TelefonoContacto = "123"
                });
            #endregion

            #region Seed Entidades
            context.Entidades.Add(new Entidad()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Nombre = "Empresa",
                Propiedades = new List<Propiedad>()
                    {
                        new Propiedad()
                        {
                            Codigo="01",
                            Nombre="Twitter",
                            TipoDeDatos="Texto"
                        }
                    }
                });
            #endregion

            #region Seed Propiedad


            #endregion

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't it work to add it to your constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're bit confused with resiliency and retry for consistency.

> Connection Resiliency refers to the ability for EF to automatically retry any commands that fail due to these connection(Network unavailability) breaks.

I wish you may not want to interfere with this as EF does it very well. From the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589799.aspx) that you mentioned, it seems like you want to use a caching pattern for your entities.

Well I can suggest you can try implementing [UnitOfWork](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to keep your context CRUD operations at one place.

Then you can implement your cache in the [UnitOfWork](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) class and fetch/create/invalidate cache items based on type of operation request.

> Make sure that cache-aside pattern doesn't give you 100% consistency. E.g. if an external operation changes the data in the DB then Cache would not be aware about that change.

Comment: I think I pasted the wrong link, but yes thanks for the information!